# A question related to the domain of a multiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Let $(X, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Given a measurable function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, define the multiplication operator $M_f$ on $L^2(X,d\mu)$ as $M_f(v)=fv$, with the domain $\mathcal{D}(M_f):=\{v \in L^2(X,d\mu): fv \in L^2(X,d\mu)\}$.

I can see why $\mathcal{D}(M_f)$ is dense in $L^2(X,d\mu)$, but I've been trying to show that $\mathcal{D}(M_f)=\mathcal{D}(M^{*}_{f})$, where $M^{*}_{f}$ is the adjoint of $M_f$.

**Remark:** The adjoint of an operator $A:\mathcal{D}(A) \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ (Hilbert space) is defined to be the unique linear map $A^*$ defined by the condition that $\langle v,Au \rangle =\langle A^*v,u \rangle$, for all $u \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ and $v \in \mathcal{D}(A^*)
$, where $\mathcal{D}(A^*):=\{v\in \mathcal{H}: u \mapsto \langle v,Au \rangle $ is a bounded functional on $\mathcal{D}(A) \}$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adjoint of $M_f$ is simply the multiplication operator by the complex-conjugate of $f$, i.e. $M_f^*=M_{\bar{f}}$. So what you are trying to show is that $fv\in L^2(\mu)$ if and only if $\bar{f}v\in L^2(\mu)$. But
$$\int_X|\bar{f}v|^2d\mu=\int_X|fv|^2d\mu$$
and thus these quantities are either both finite or both infinite, since they are equal.